# Soundpool not working and some devices

Tags: android, soundpool

I found many questions regarding Soundpool but they all state that it is not working at all. for me the case is different.

i have declared a soundpool object and track ids as follow

```
public static SoundPool sp;
public static int comeCloseID, goFurtherID, blinkID, smileID, rotateLeftID, rotateRightID;
```

then i have created a initSounds function to initialize the sound pool

```
public static void initSounds()
{
    sp = new SoundPool.Builder().build();
    comeCloseID = sp.load(mContext, R.raw.comeclose,1);
    goFurtherID = sp.load(mContext, R.raw.gofurther,1);
    blinkID = sp.load(mContext, R.raw.blink, 1);
    smileID = sp.load(mContext, R.raw.smile, 1);
    rotateLeftID = sp.load(mContext, R.raw.rotateleft, 1);
    rotateRightID = sp.load(mContext, R.raw.rotateright, 1);

    sp.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                                   int status) {
            loaded = true;
        }
    });
}
```

then i paly the sounds as follows:

```
GlobalParams.sp.play(GlobalParams.comeCloseID, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
```

etc...

the audio files paly well using my samsung note5 device. but when i try them on a J1 device or a lenovo device the sounds wont play. (thogh i can log the value of loaded to be true).

what have i missed? and why the audio isn't playing?

Knowing that I tried using different formats for the audio (WAV, MP3....) but id didnt solve the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing `setMaxStreams(5)` to say 5, you have it set to default of 1:

```
AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_COMMUNICATION_INSTANT)
                    .build();

sp = new SoundPool.Builder()
.setMaxStreams(5)
.setAudioAttributes(attributes)
.build();
```